# How do I define an embedded language with semantic highlighting from the outer language?

Tags: monaco-editor, monaco-languageserver

I am writing a language syntax definition for my custom language which has embedded SQL. The custom language will define some table names which I'd like the embedded SQL state to be semantically aware of, for example:

```
// root state
TableFoo = buildTableFoo()

<sql>
// embedded sql state
SELECT *
FROM TableFoo
</sql>
```

Per this example, I'd like TableFoo be highlighted as it's been previously defined in the root state. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am also looking solution for this, any luck in finding solution?